# How to change windows order in gnome?

Tags: linux, bash, x11, gnome-shell

For example:

List the windows being managed by the window manager.

```
wmctrl -l
0x1 blabla1
0x2 blabla2
0x3 blabla3
0x4 blabla4
```

Swap window 1 with window 4.

```
$magic_command 1 4
```

What I want:

```
wmctrl -l
0x3 blabla4
0x2 blabla2
0x3 blabla3
0x1 blabla1
```

How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "swap window 1 with window 3"?

Comment: @n.m. "swap" here means "change of position".

Comment: @n.m. Maybe my example is confusing. Edited now :)

Comment: How do you imagine sorting windows according to their position? Whatever your answer is, there are many other equally possible answers. `wmctl` doesn't do any of that. If you want some particular flavour of output sorted by position, you need to write some code.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for your guidance :)